# Angular Templates not loading but the outlets do

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

My template outlets load fine in the browser but the component template html does not load. The components are generated with CLI. not sure what's wrong here. [yes,i looked through template questions here on SO for hours.]

Here is what the browser renders.

[image]

Here is my main.layout.component.html

```
Test
<app-header></app-header>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

This is my header template and component for example. (footer is similar.)

Template

```
<p>
  header works!
</p>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is the layout module that declares all the components.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
    ],
    exports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        AuthLayoutComponent,
        MainLayoutComponent,
        EmptyLayoutComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ]
})
export class AppLayoutModule { }
```

Here is the structure. I am not getting any console errors etc. thanks for any help.
[image]

**UPDATE:**

If I add HeaderComponent in AppModule declarations the header template loads!
Am i doing something wrong with my structure? Why do I need to declare a child module's(LayoutModule) components in higher modules(AppModule) for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The must be **only one** `<router-outlet>` for angular application. Cause `<router-outlet>` render components by a given route.

Comment: angular application can have multiple router outlets in different modules and subcomponents....to load more child components/modules...

Answer (score 0):

after a walk i figured out the issue. I did not export the components; therefore parent module was not able to find the component templates. Here is a correct AppLayoutModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent,
        AuthLayoutComponent,
        MainLayoutComponent,
        EmptyLayoutComponent,
    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        AuthLayoutComponent,
        MainLayoutComponent,
        EmptyLayoutComponent,
        FooterComponent,
    ]
})
export class AppLayoutModule { }
```